# Zoom in and out in selenium Webdriver using VisualStudio C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, webdriver

I want to `ZoomIn` and later `ZoomOut` using below code but its not working.

```
public void ZoomIn()
{
    new Actions(driver)
        .SendKeys(Keys.Control).SendKeys(Keys.Add)
        .Perform();
}

public void ZoomOut()
{
    new Actions(driver)
        .SendKeys(Keys.Control).SendKeys(Keys.Subtract)
        .Perform();
}
```

Is there any other way - please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: What the reason to zoom your page in tests?

Comment: Screen size - elements are not visible on screen so Selenium is not able to find the element.

Comment: not visible? than you need get more domain knowledge about what actually mean visibility for Selenium. So looks like element is present in DOM but not clickable at this time. Yes you can hack it with JS but it not the best way to do it - because it's not a user flow off course if you care about.

Comment: Yes - I mean its present in DOM but not clickable - So I used pageUp and pageDown to make it clickable. - I got your point - Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=667387

---

Alternatively, you can set the browser's zoom level via JavaScript:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='110%'");
```

---

Example:

```
private int ZoomValue = 100;
private int ZoomIncrement = 10;

public void ZoomIn()
{
    ZoomValue += ZoomIncrement;
    Zoom(ZoomValue);
}
public void ZoomOut()
{
    ZoomValue -= ZoomIncrement;
    Zoom(ZoomValue);
}
private void Zoom(int level)
{
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript(string.Format("document.body.style.zoom='{0}%'", level));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Budi - It works perfectly fine. - Appreciate for your help.